# How to add artificial shadow to a poster?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, photo-editing, adobe-premiere

I see this nowadays a lot. It's not just the picture being sharpened, but they added shadows too. In this NBA example, I am sure there couldn't be just one light bulb in the entire arena casting one shadow for each object. What software do people usually use to create this effect, Premiere Pro, Photoshop or something else?

[image]

Here is a before and after comparison from a real NBA game.
[image]

Comment: I could be wrong, but that *appears* to be a 3D renderings from a video game (It's not a "sharpened photo"). 3D excels at creating cast shadows easily.

Comment: I thought that too at first, but I added in a comparison from a real NBA game to show that it is not a video game.

Comment: the shadows are from multiple simultaneous camera flashes (left) vs ambient light (right). There are usually banks of photographers at each end of the court and they tend to all shoot for the action. Clearly something is happening in this moment, and a volley of photos have been taken at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yorik in the comments is most likely right.

The images you are posting are not before and after, they are just milliseconds away when two lighting situations occurred. The first one has hard lights, point lights probably from flashes from photographers, and the second is the ambient light of the court.

2. A normal 2D program can not generate a shadow that is not the exact copy of a masked silhouette. A simple Google search will help you if that kind of shadow is enough for you: https://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop/drop-shadow.html
3. But you could enhance a photo that has no shadows with one project from a different source of light using a 3D program. You could create a dummy figure, with more or less the same body position and use the generated shadow to merge that one into the original scene.
4. Probably some AI-assisted software can help you simplify this. Either to redraw your image with a different relight, or to generate 3D assets, or the pose, or the full scene.